# Введение в java олимпиадное программирование

Tags: java, c++, олимпиада

Перевожу свои скудные знания с [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) на [java](/questions/tagged/java). Поделитесь основными методами?

Например, в c++ для ввода используют ввод `cin`, нужно быстрее - `scanf`, еще быстрей - `cin` + `(Sync.tool`.....), а если совсем быстро, то считать строку и разбить побитово.

Кроме того, чем заменить ввод данных `while(( c= getchar()) != EOF)`. Какие есть аналоги на java и что еще может быть полезным? Вот пример задачи (http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/550/A?locale=ru)

Comment: лучше бы там этот вопрос задали. Вроде бы на CF обсуждали уже всякие fast scanner - ы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот [здесь](http://acm.timus.ru/help.aspx?topic=java) даны соответствующие рекомендации, как раз в приложении к олимпиадному программированию:

- [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) является самым удобным средством для чтения входных данных в большинстве задач, но скорость его работы оставляет желать лучшего. Используйте его только для чтения небольших входных данных.
- [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) обеспечивает достаточно быстрый ввод для большинства задач. Но самостоятельно этот класс позволяет лишь читать отдельные символы и строки. Для чтения токенов и чисел используйте [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) или [StreamTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html).
- [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) подходит для всех случаев и работает достаточно быстро. Но его метод `printf` работает медленно; также медленно работают вызовы типа `println(a + " " + b)`. Выводите по одной переменной за раз (через `print`/`println`), и тогда вы добьетесь максимальной эффективности.